# JPA JOIN Query issue

Tags: java, jpa

I'm experimenting with JPA queries  but keep getting an error on the following query

```
SELECT p
FROM usertype_permissions up
JOIN permissions p ON up.PERMISSION_ID = p.ID
WHERE up.USERTYPE_ID = 1
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while
creating a query in EntityManager: 

Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query
[SELECT p
FROM usertype_permissions up
JOIN permissions p ON up.PERMISSION_ID = p.ID
WHERE up.USERTYPE_ID = 1].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JPQL you have to use Entity names (by default it's the name of the Java class), to me it looks weird that `usertype_permissions` is an Entity name / Java class...

It looks like you are using table names and the word after join has to refer to an attribute of a class e.g. `l.books`

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Lib implements Serializable {
      @OneToMany
      private Set<Book> books;
}

@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {
      @OneToOne
      private Lib lib;
}
```

a JPQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT l FROM Lib JOIN l.books books
```

Comment: usertype_permissions is not a class, it's the table generated because of to ManyToMany relationship...

How can I get data out of that table?

Comment: I suppose you have a class User with a collection of Permission objects then... I guess you want to get the permissons for one user? 
then just do: SELECT u.permissions FROM User u where u.id = 1